# Compare two numeric variables by two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

How I can build ggplot2 graph with two numeric variables on x axis as mean and sd, by two groups? As an example: on the left hand preoperative Hb value, by 2 groups and on the right the postoperative Hb values by the same 2 groups.

[image]

Comment: Could you please expand your question, perhaps attach a hand drawn figure of the final output you're after, perhaps offer some simulated data and code?

Comment: I ' ve got two groups in variable age_gr -- factor var: levels: younger than 65 and the second one - older 65, Two numeric variables Hb1 - preoperative  value -- 145.2, and second numeric Hb2 - with postoperative values as example - 125.7. In the first group 47 patients and in the second one (older than 65 yr. - 53) And I like to see results on one graph, comparing  these two groups.

Comment: Roman, I posted the picture in Question box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this similar to what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

# creating some nonsense sample data
x <- iris %>%
  select(-Petal.Width,-Sepal.Width) %>%
  melt(id.vars="Species") %>%
  group_by_at(colnames(select_if(.,negate(is.numeric)))) %>%
  summarise_all(mean,na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(sd01=value-value/10,
         sd02=value+value/10) %>%
  rename(mean=value,
         groups=variable)

# plotting
ggplot(x,aes(Species,mean,color=Species))+
  geom_point(stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=sd01,ymax=sd02))+
  facet_wrap(~groups, strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  annotate("segment", x = 0, y = 0, xend = 4, yend = 0)
```

[image]

EDIT: using `geom_pointrange()` makes the code shorter and changes the look of the errorbar.

```
ggplot(x,aes(Species,mean,color=Species))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=sd01,ymax=sd02),stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~groups, strip.position = "bottom")+...
```

[image]

Comment: I' ve posted the picture, I asked this Quest. because never seen in any book and web.

Comment: Alex, Thanks a lot, but can I do this without facet?

Comment: See the edit. I suppose this is what you want. Please note that you'll probably need the wrap in order to create the second level on the x-axis. With the panel spacing you can make it appear as one axis, though. In order to get your age groups into the plot, you'll need only one variable with the values and another one with all the categories (both age groups and mean and sd), i.e. "long" format. Therefore, use a function like `melt()` once your dataset is ready in "wide" format.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the suggestion; I extended the answer.

Comment: @Gennady_F Don't forget to check the answer if it answers your question. Thank you.

Comment: Alex, Thank's a lot, it's really what I asked for!

Comment: Thank you, but I actually meant clicking the green check-mark to the left of the answer. This helps others find the correct answer to the question.